# Consecutively regex-replace separated values

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, datagrid, replace

Reading a raster grid file into `@grid` containing arbitrary numbers, like

```
82 8 98 98 42 12 3342 321 34 34 09434 9232
```

(and many more of those rows).

Herein, I do like to replace some numbers, like 34 with 42.
But only single, separated numbers! Eg. I do not want to replace the 34 in 3342.

So for numbers $a (search,eg 34) and $b (replace, eg 42), my approach is

```
s/(^|\s)$a(\s|$)/$1$b$2/g for @grid;
```

But this only replaces every second of consecutive occurrences (like `34 34 34 34`=>`42 34 42 34`), because the suffix `\s` is not taken into account as prefix of the next pattern.

Is there any solution for this problem, other than putting two of those commands back-to-back (which is slow for large arrays)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `\b` : the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char

```
s/\b$a\b/$b/g
```

<kbd>[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kY7lH6)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a hash that contains your replacement pairs, and then capture each number on a line and do the replacement if that number's a hash key:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %replacements = ( 34 => 42, 8 => 100 );

while (<DATA>) {
    s/(\d+)/exists $replacements{$1} ? $replacements{$1} : $1/ge;
    print;
}

__DATA__
82 8 98 98 42 12 3342 321 34 34 09434 9232
97 8 8 8 27 37 34 55 19 100 8 34 07932 8
```

Output:

```
82 100 98 98 42 12 3342 321 42 42 09434 9232
97 100 100 100 27 37 42 55 19 100 100 42 07932 100
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Quite an elegant solution, but `/e` seems to have low performance.